# How can I describe my eye weakness (disease) to a doctor?

Tags: eye

5 days ago, I found that my right eye does not work properly. The vision of the left eye is better.

Here is how I feel:

When a person press strongly on his closed eye by his figures or hand, The vision becomes unclear temporarily. This is how I see but I see it permanently.

When a person look at the sun or a strong light, Then the vision in a normal lighted room becomes unclear. This is how I feel too.

I think I have a problem with the **brightness** of the right eye. I don't have issue with **colours** or **resolution**. I do NOT see a **blurry** image. My problem is with **light** I think. I also see kind of **floaters**.

Soon, I will go to a doctor. What is the best way to describe my problem? so that he checks me correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure the description you give here is enough for a doctor.

Please take a look at this: http://www.webmd.com/eye-health/benign-eye-floaters

WebMD is a reliable source. They state:

> If you only have a few eye floaters that don't change over time, don’t
>   sweat it.
>
> Go to the doctor ASAP if you notice:
>
> - A sudden increase in the number of floaters
> - Flashes of light
> - A loss ofside vision Changes that come on quickly and get worse over time
> - Floaters after eye surgery or eye trauma Eye pain
>
> Choose a doctor who has experience with retina problems. If you don’t get help right away, you could lose your sight.

Comment: Your first sentence is the answer. What he describes doesn't sound like floaters.

Comment: Indeed. However, when I press my eyeball firmly, the vision doesn't become unclear; it turns totally dark, making me think of occluding either the optic nerve, or either the ophthalmic artery, in which latter case it would mean that the receptors (cones & rods) are extremely oxygen dependent and sensitive. Should look this up; whether it is the CN II or the A. ophtalmica you compress while doing that ... That aside; I hope you get better soon!