# How a person with high eye pressure see? Would you give me pictures?

Tags: blurry-vision, field-of-vision-fov-test, intraocular-pressure-iop, glaucoma

After asking this question:
[How can I describe my eye weakness (disease) to a doctor?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/10255/how-can-i-describe-my-eye-weakness-disease-to-a-doctor)

I went to an occultist. He said that my eye sight is 6/6 (good) and eye bottom is good healthy too. He did not check my eye pressure and said I'm OK generally. I sitll have bad vision with my right eye.

I went to other two oculists, They said I've an issue with eye pressure and I've to check my field of vision.

Now, I would like you to send my some picture about how a person who have an issue with eye pressure see the world? 
It would be very very useful for me to describe my issue?

Maybe I see something like white/Gray spot or cloud?! ... Anyway, I can not describe. Please, Help me by sending the pictures if you have one.

Thank you very much,

Comment: I guess the term you are looking for is [ocular hypertension](http://www.emedicinehealth.com/ocular_hypertension/article_em.htm). It's a scientific term for high eye presure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most cases of high eye pressure leads to [glaucoma](http://www.glaucoma.org/gleams/high-eye-pressure-and-glaucoma.php), the picture below shows how someone with glaucoma sees the world

[image]

Comment: Except you are not aware of the missing field... it's not black, it just isn't there.